# Show first data in repeat header table php

Tags: php

I was print with repeat header when page_break is active every 40 row. 
But with manual query : show 49 data. But when implement in this code. The result show start from 1 end 48 data.
How to show first data in table in page 1, and not show in page 2?

Sorry, I can't write this code in here, show warning "not formatted as code". I use [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/knacyAt6).

Thanks

Comment: No one here wants to read through that much code to answer a question you haven't clearly defined. Please see [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: any clue for me? maybe i show screenshot?

Comment: @deib97 show a screenshot of your current result and perhaps an illustration of what you would like the code to achieve?